# Custom MessageBox at run time in C#

Tags: c#, messagebox

Is there an easy way (or perhaps a third-party implementation) to programmatically create a `MessageBox` with various types of controls on it? Ideally, with some sort of scripting language (ie. XML).

I would prefer not to code this myself from scratch.

Comment: This question is hard to understand. What platform are you using?

Comment: Windows. I'm using Windows.Forms currently.

Comment: Customized form is the easiest way out for this. You can just call it every time you need it.

Comment: Perhaps this could help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932792/how-to-create-a-custom-messagebox?lq=1

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this. One is called WinForms, the other WPF. The latter even uses an XML language (called XAML). Since you didn’t specify what kinds of controls you need, this is the best answer I can offer to your question because it covers the widest available range of controls.

Comment: I will be adding things like checkboxes, radio buttons, textboxes, updown controls, and dropdowns.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not create a form and customise it as a compromise?

Comment: This is my backup method. I would add some sort of XML parsing on top to make it customizable.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question.
Custom MessageBoxes are much simpler to create than what I thought.

[How to create a custom MessageBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932792/how-to-create-a-custom-messagebox)