# How to create a custom MessageBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, messagebox

I'm trying to make a custom message box with my controls.

```
public static partial class Msg : Form
{
    public static void show(string content, string description)
    {

    }
}
```

Actually I need to place some controls (a gridview) in this form and I have to apply my own theme for this window, so I don't want to use `MessageBox`. I want to call this from my other forms like

```
Msg.show(parameters);
```

I don't wish to create an object for this form.

I know I can't inherit from `Form` class because it isn't static. But I wonder how `MessageBox` is implemented, because it is static. It is being called like `MessageBox.show("Some message!");`

Now I'm getting an error because inheritance is not allowed:

> Static class 'MyFormName' cannot derive from type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'. Static classes must derive from object

[image: Screenshot of my form]

How `MessageBox` is implemented then?

Comment: .NET's MessageBox is just a wrapper for the MessageBox that is part of Win32. You will need to create a Form object for your custom MessageBox. Possibly make it a singleton. Or just create a new Form, show it, and then dispose it each time `Msg.Show()` is called.

Comment: `Msg` class doesn't have to be static for `show` to be static.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your form class needs not to be `static`. In fact, **a static class cannot inherit at all**.

Instead, **create an `internal` form class that derives from `Form` and provide a `public static` helper method to show it**.

This static method **may be defined in a different class** if you don't want the callers to even “know” about the underlying form.

```
/// <summary>
/// The form internally used by <see cref="CustomMessageBox"/> class.
/// </summary>
internal partial class CustomMessageForm : Form
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This constructor is required for designer support.
    /// </summary>
    public CustomMessageForm ()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
    } 

    public CustomMessageForm (string title, string description)
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 

        this.titleLabel.Text = title;
        this.descriptionLabel.Text = description;
    } 
}

/// <summary>
/// Your custom message box helper.
/// </summary>
public static class CustomMessageBox
{
    public static void Show (string title, string description)
    {
        // using construct ensures the resources are freed when form is closed
        using (var form = new CustomMessageForm (title, description)) {
            form.ShowDialog ();
        }
    }
}
```

Side note: as Jalal [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932792/how-to-do-a-c-messagebox-like-static-form/6932846#6932846), you don't have to make a class `static` in order to have `static` methods in it. But I would still separate the “helper” class from the actual form so the callers cannot create the form with a constructor (unless they're in the same assembly of course).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply..

I did the form..
Thank you Dan Abramov for a different Answer with internal class usage :)

Comment: yeah, by using this internal class, I could prevent calling constructors, It was a new concept for me...

Thank you once again for explaining.

Comment: Yeah—but this only works when you define these classes in a separate assembly. Another option would be to declare the `Form` class *inside* the static helper and declare it `private` but you would lose the designer so I think this isn't worth it.

Comment: using (var form = new CustomMessageForm (title, description)) {
            form.ShowDialog ();} could you explain why you used var?
.......... 
new CustomMessageForm (title, description).showDialog();
is this code has any problem to be a well programmed code? Sorry, I didn't got much chance to learn these concepts. I just want to learn these best practices

Comment: @BeediKumaraN: `var` lets the compiler infer the type for you so you don't have to write the name twice `CustomMessageForm form = new CustomMessageForm`. I suggest you [google this](http://google.com/search?q=var+c%23) first and also read [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c). Generally, please post a new question on its own instead of discussion in comments.

Comment: If I want to create two buttons in this custom message box (Ok, Cancel), how would I do to get what button was pressed to terminate the Message box ? I tried to return a DialogResult from the Show Method but it causes trouble with non-static member

Answer (score 5):

You don't need the class to be static.
Just do something like:

```
public partial class Msg : Form
{
    public static void show(string content, string description)
    {
         Msg message = new Msg(...);
         message.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 because you don't free the resources (and also `Show` isn't modal, you should call `ShowDialog`).

Answer (score 2):

**You don't need to make the class `static` in order to call one of its methods statically** — it's sufficient to declare the particular method as `static`.

```
public partial class DetailedMessageBox : Form
{
    public DetailedMessageBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static void ShowMessage(string content, string description)
    {
        DetailedMessageBox messageBox = new DetailedMessageBox();
        messageBox.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

We are using `messageBox.ShowDialog()` to have the form being displayed as a *modal* window. You can display the message box using `DetailedMessageBox.ShowMessage("Content", "Description");`.

By the way, you should rethink your naming and stick to a consistent naming pattern. `Msg` and `show` are weak names that do no match the [Naming Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) — you would definitely want to check those out!

Comment: Sure, I'll check those Naming Conventions. thank you for pointing that.

Answer (score -2):

In a WPF project you can add a new window and call it MessageBoxCustom then inside C# the Void where you can find InitialiseComponent();  you add 2 properties and bind those properties to the textBlocks you should have created inside your XAML view
Example:

```
public MessageBoxCustom(string Message, string Title)
{
    InitialiseComponent();//this comes first to load Front End
    textblock1.Text = Title;
    textblock2.Text = Message;
}

Just position your TextBlocks where you want them to be displayed in XAML


From your Main Window you can call that message box like this


private void Button_Click()
{
    MessageBoxCustom msg = new MessageBoxCustom("Your message here","Your title her");
    msg.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: *"In a WPF project"* - that's right, but the answer is clearly tagged both `forms` and `winforms`...