# custom single line messagebox

Tags: c#, messagebox

I'm trying to make a custom message box for my application. The problem is, I want to code it in a way so that I can use it as regular message box.

```
MyCustomBox("My Message");
```

intead of doing

```
FormMessage frm = new FormMessage();
frm.message = "My Message";
frm.show();
```

How can I accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932792/how-to-create-a-custom-messagebox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a static method to `FormMessage` class

```
public static void ShowBox(string message)
{
    using (FormMessage frm = new FormMessage())
    {
        frm.Message = message;
        frm.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

And then

```
FormMessage.ShowBox("My Message");
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the form with the appropriate controls, etc.  Then add a static method to the class that handles all the messy bits - creating an instance (if necessary), setting properties, etc.

I wish I could write more on this, but it's pretty simple stuff.  Just call `MyCustomBox.ShowMessage()` or whatever you call the static method.