# Winform messagebox, How to disable YESNO options in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

I want to show YesNoCancel button in the message box, but at the same time, I wanted to disable YesNo button and enable only Cancel button.

The reason I wanted to do like this is I am doing a demo application where I want to show users that particular feature is available but at the same time I don't want to give them save access.

Following is my code, now to how to Disable YesNo button.

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Save changes to " + this.Text.Substring(0, this.Text.Length - 1) + "?",
                                      "Save confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
```

Actually I want to show YesNo buttons but I wanted to disable click acess for it. I wanted to show users 3 buttons YES , No and Cancel but click acess should be given only to cancel button. Is that possible?

**edit:
Thanks all for the answers.**

**I have found soultion for my question**

**My code for custom message box, I hope this might help someone**

**customMsgBox.cs**

```
enter code here { public partial class CustomMsgBox : Form
{
    static CustomMsgBox MsgBox;
    static string Button_id;

    public CustomMsgBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    internal static string ShowBox(string txtMessage, enumMessageIcon messageIcon)
    {
        MsgBox = new CustomMsgBox();
        MsgBox.labelCustomMsg.Text = txtMessage;
        MsgBox.addIconImage(messageIcon);
        MsgBox.ShowDialog();
        return Button_id;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// We can use this method to add image on message box.
    /// I had taken all images in ImageList control so that
    /// I can easily add images. Image is displayed in 
    /// PictureBox control.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="MessageIcon">Type of image to be displayed.</param>
    private void addIconImage(enumMessageIcon MessageIcon)
    {
        switch (MessageIcon)
        {
            case enumMessageIcon.Error:
                pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images["Error"];  //Error is key 
                //name in imagelist control which uniquely identified images 
                //in ImageList control.
                break;
            case enumMessageIcon.Information:
                pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images["Information"];
                break;
            case enumMessageIcon.Question:
                pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images["Question"];
                break;
            case enumMessageIcon.Warning:
                pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images["Warning"];
                break;
        }
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button_id = "Cancel";
        MsgBox.Dispose();
    }

    private void btnNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button_id = "No";
        MsgBox.Dispose();
    }

    private void btnYes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button_id = "Yes";
        MsgBox.Dispose();
    }
}

#region constant defiend in form of enumration which is used in showMessage class.

internal enum enumMessageIcon
{
    Error,
    Warning,
    Information,
    Question,
}

internal enum enumMessageButton
{
    OK,
    YesNo,
    YesNoCancel,
    OKCancel
}

#endregion
```

}

**main.cs**

```
String customResult = CustomMsgBox.ShowBox("Save changes to " + this.Text.Substring(0, this.Text.Length - 1) + "?", enumMessageIcon.Question);
```

Comment: Just make your own dialog instead of using the built in one.

Comment: Why don't you create own message box with buttons?

Comment: Am new to c#. I don't no how to create own message box.

Comment: You have to create your custom dialog box and manage it.

Comment: Its Simple once you google how to do it. Follow this guide: https://youtu.be/MkFE_pM7jOc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`MessageBoxButtons`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxbuttons(v=vs.110).aspx) Enumerations does not have such options, It contains the following members

[image]

So the better option for you is a custom message box, for this you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932792/how-to-create-a-custom-messagebox), [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/327212/Custom-Message-Box-in-VC) or [this](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_general/eventsanddelegates/article.php/c13193/Creating-a-Custom-Message-Box.htm), Or simply follow the recipe,

- Create a Form(let it be `frmMessage`) with a constructor accepts a string value that is the message that you wanted to display,
- Give an appropriate title Text, let it be `Save confirmation`,
- Place a Label to display the message in the label from the constructor.
- Place Three buttons, Give name and Text for them,
- Disable the Two(Yes/No), Your message box is ready

Usage Example:

Now you need to create an object of this message box and call them like the following:

```
frmMessage frmMessageInstance = new frmMessage("Save changes to " + this.Text.Substring(0, this.Text.Length - 1) + "?");
frmMessageInstance.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Actually I want YesNo buttons but I wanted to disable click acess for it. I wanted to show users 3 buttons YES , No and Cancel but click acess should be given only to cancel button. Is that possible?

Comment: can you suggest me how to make message button to default for the code which can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41235881/custom-dialog-result-for-the-following-custom-message-box

Comment: @kaviarasan That question already have an accepted answer, right? then what you need more?

Comment: I want to make Ok button as default. Since buttons are created at run time how to make a particular button to default?

Answer (score 0):

As explained by [Un-lucky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5195227/un-lucky), the only way you can do that is by creating your own custom `messageBox`. I would do something like this

```
/// <summary>
/// The form internally used by <see cref="CustomMessageBox"/> class.
/// </summary>
internal partial class CustomMessageForm : Form
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This constructor is required for designer support.
    /// </summary>
    public CustomMessageForm ()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 
    } 

    public CustomMessageForm (string title, string description)
    {
        InitializeComponent(); 

        this.titleLabel.Text = title;
        this.descriptionLabel.Text = description;
    } 
}

/// <summary>
/// Your custom message box helper.
/// </summary>
public static class CustomMessageBox
{
    public static void Show (string title, string description)
    {
        // using construct ensures the resources are freed when form is closed
        using (var form = new CustomMessageForm (title, description)) {
            form.ShowDialog ();
        }
    }
}
```

Graciously copied from an answer by [Dan Abramov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/458193/dan-abramov) for question [How to create a custom MessageBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932792/how-to-create-a-custom-messagebox)