# Custom Dialog result for the following custom message box

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

How can I implement custom dialog result for the following code, what all the changes I need to make in the following code to get the dialog result?

```
private void addButton(enumMessageButton MessageButton)
    {
        switch (MessageButton)
        {
            case enumMessageButton.OK:
                {
                    //If type of enumButton is OK then we add OK button only.
                    Button btnOk = new Button();  //Create object of Button.
                    btnOk.Text = "OK";  //Here we set text of Button.
                    btnOk.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;  //Set DialogResult property of button.
                    btnOk.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup;  //Set flat appearence of button.
                    btnOk.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
                    btnOk.SetBounds(pnlShowMessage.ClientSize.Width - 80, 5, 75, 25);  // Set bounds of button.
                    pnlShowMessage.Controls.Add(btnOk);  //Finally Add button control on panel.
                }
                break;
            case enumMessageButton.OKCancel:
                {
                    Button btnOk = new Button();
                    btnOk.Text = "OK";
                    btnOk.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
                    btnOk.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup;
                    btnOk.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
                    btnOk.SetBounds((pnlShowMessage.ClientSize.Width - 70), 5, 65, 25);
                    pnlShowMessage.Controls.Add(btnOk);

                    Button btnCancel = new Button();
                    btnCancel.Text = "Cancel";
                    btnCancel.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
                    btnCancel.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup;
                    btnCancel.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
                    btnCancel.SetBounds((pnlShowMessage.ClientSize.Width - (btnOk.ClientSize.Width + 5 + 80)), 5, 75, 25);
                    pnlShowMessage.Controls.Add(btnCancel);

                }
                break;
        }
    }

internal static void ShowBox(string messageText, string messageTitle, enumMessageIcon messageIcon, enumMessageButton messageButton)
    {
        frmShowMessage frmMessage = new frmShowMessage();
        frmMessage.setMessage(messageText);
        frmMessage.Text = messageTitle;
        frmMessage.addIconImage(messageIcon);
        frmMessage.addButton(messageButton);
        frmMessage.ShowDialog();
    }
```

**Main.cs**

```
frmShowMessage.ShowBox("This is message box which represent message with title, custome button and custom icon.", "This is message title", enumMessageIcon.Question, enumMessageButton.OKCancel);
```

Now how do further I implement code to get dialog result?

Comment: `internal static DialogResult ShowBox(...` and use `return fromShowMessage.ShowDialog();`

Comment: Thanks, this worked

Comment: I tried to set return value as DialogResult initially before posting this question where it was Void. But failed to set the return "return frmMessage.ShowDialog();" How dumb I am. Anyways now this works. Special thx to Ivan Stoev

Comment: can you suggest me a method to make message button to default with the above code from my question?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by *to make message button to default*. You might consider posting another question providing details of what do you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
internal static void ShowBox(string messageText, string messageTitle, enumMessageIcon messageIcon, enumMessageButton messageButton)
{
    frmShowMessage frmMessage = new frmShowMessage();
    frmMessage.setMessage(messageText);
    frmMessage.Text = messageTitle;
    frmMessage.addIconImage(messageIcon);
    frmMessage.addButton(messageButton);
    frmMessage.ShowDialog();
}
```

try this

```
internal static DialogResult ShowBox(string messageText, string messageTitle, enumMessageIcon messageIcon, enumMessageButton messageButton)
{
    frmShowMessage frmMessage = new frmShowMessage();
    frmMessage.setMessage(messageText);
    frmMessage.Text = messageTitle;
    frmMessage.addIconImage(messageIcon);
    frmMessage.addButton(messageButton);
    return frmMessage.ShowDialog();
}
```

Comment: can you suggest me how to make message button to default with the above code from my question?

Answer (score 0):

You have the formMessage object, adding controls and calling showDialog().
Note that when the ShowDialog returns, you still have the object frmMessage and
you can access the methods and properties on that object.

So when the corresponding buttons are clicked, you could set a property in your 
fromMessage class on what button is pressed. Perhaps you have some additional fields that you can set.

After the showDialog returns, you can access those properties, perhaps construct your own DialogResult and return that result